# Docker on Mac pre-2010?

Tags: docker, containers, osx-elcapitan

Is there a workaround to install Docker for OSX on Macs without Intel's hardware support for MMU virtualization?

If not, would there be a workaround to create containers, e.g. for Python scripts and libraries?

Comment: Specific to Python, you can contain your application using virtualenvs. Many other languages support a similar model, such as Ruby gems, Node.js and node_modules... these may be helpful since you are not able to use Docker for containment at this point.

Comment: Did you try older approach with [docker toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/). It runs on my Mac mini (mid 2010) which reports `kern.hv_support: 0` and actually has not supported hardware to enable VT-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Q1 2019, [Antonio Linares Cañas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1247270/antonio-linares-ca%C3%B1as) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739794/docker-on-mac-pre-2010/47739858#comment97064770_47739858):

"**[Enable VT-X on Mac Pro (Early 2008) - KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Enable_VT-X_on_Mac_Pro_(Early_2008))**" from **GeorgeStyles**, with a program that will tell you the status of your MSR (manufacturer specific register, on all cores), and if its unlocked and off, will attempt to turn on VTX and lock it on.

See also [msrtool](https://www.coreboot.org/Msrtool) or **[voltageshift](https://sitechprog.blogspot.com/2017/06/voltageshift.html)**.
Example:

```
cd /Applications/voltageshift 
sudo chmod -R 755 VoltageShift.kext 
sudo chown -R root:wheel VoltageShift.kext 
sudo ./voltageshift read 0x3a 
a value of 0x5 means: ON-cero-LOCKED
```

---

Original answer Dec. 2017:

I don't know of a workaround, but as [mentioned here](https://forums.docker.com/t/fatal-error-incompatible-cpu-detected/9162/6):

> On OS X, the way of knowing if your CPU complies with all the `Hypervisor.framework` requirements is by checking the value of the `sysctl kern.hv_support` key.

```
$ sysctl kern.hv_support
kern.hv_support: 1
```

> If it is 1, then your CPU is supported.
>   If it is 0, it means the Hypervisor.framework cannot be used with your CPU, for a reason or another.

The [same thread adds](https://forums.docker.com/t/fatal-error-incompatible-cpu-detected/9162/14):

> My CPU supports all virtualization, including EPT, VT-d and VT-x:
>   http://ark.intel.com/products/41316/Intel-Core-i7-860-Processor-8M-Cache-2_80-GHz53
>
> The problem is that the BIOS setting is set by default to '0' or 'disabled' instead of '1' or 'enabled'
>
> There is a HUGE user group that this is affecting but most have no idea how to check so it doesn't get reported - millions of laptops/desktops sold over many years are experiencing this.
>
> There has to be a way to change the BIOS setting from 0 to 1.

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for the immediate reply. Unfortunately my CPU is not supported `kern.hv_support 0` which is why I am curious..

Comment: @MichaelScott Yes, and I mentioned the BIOS as well. But if there is no support for the hypervisor, that means there is no easy way to add virtualization or containarisation.

Comment: @AntonioLinaresCañas Thank you. I have included those links in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: https://sitechprog.blogspot.com/2017/06/voltageshift.html                               For read the MSR
 ./voltageshift read 0xMSR 
For set the MSR
./voltageshift write 0xMSR 0xValue

Comment: In msrmagic.c from the first url we find this: int addr = 0x3a; // VTX enable, so to use voltageshift we do: sudo ./voltageshift read 0x3a. Here on a iMac late 2009 returns 0x5

Comment: @AntonioLinaresCañas Can you edit directly the answer?  I will approve the edit and it will avoid too many comments ;)